# Is there an Operating System developed using Lisp?

Tags: operating-system, lisp, common-lisp

I was wondering if there is an Operating System developed using LISP alone?

I also would like to know if there is any Open Source project developing an OS under LISP. The language is pretty exciting and I look forward to establish my programming mostly in LISP.

Comment: this question does not belong to Stackoverflow. The FAQ: **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.**
Plus a simple look at Google and Wikipedia would have expanded your general knowledge as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Movitz is an operating system written in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like the big old [Lisp Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine)?

Comment: Umm.. I am more interested to know if any OS was / is being developed using LISP.

Comment: That's what Lisp Machines are written in (thus the name...).